# Using requirejs for a modular game engine

Tags: javascript, requirejs, game-engine

I'm an experienced javascript programmer, and I'm trying to write my own modular game engine from scratch. I haven't used requirejs before, but after reading a bit about it, it sounds like it's probably the best way to manage all the components of the engine and load them into one coherent structure.

My main problem is that I'm not really sure how to really use requirejs. I've been looking over their API documentation, but I'm not sure how to integrate it with the way I've laid out my project.

Currently, my project uses the following structure:

> - src
>
>   - engine.js                 *//This contains the common engine stuff, most notably the engine namespace*
>   - resource
>
>     - resource-module.js      *//This is the module constructor, which handles all the common stuff between the different
>         substructures*
>     - sprites.js              *//This is a substructure that contains sprite loading code*
>   - render
>   - etc...
>   - third-party
>
>     - jquery
>     - requirejs

I want to be able to load the modules independently of each other. It should be possible for instance to remove the audio module from the engine, and it still work. It should also be easy to substitute modules, or add new modules.

Also, I'm using jQuery for event handling, so it needs to be loaded before the engine is initiated.

You can find my current source here: https://github.com/superlinkx/lithium-engine

I know the current code is messy, and there isn't a whole lot built yet, but I'm mostly still figuring out how to best structure it. Any help/advice would be appreciated, but my main concern is how to structure it with requirejs so that it will be easier to compile into a single file for production use.

Comment: You have a lot of source files, how are they currently used? As individual `<script>` tags?

Comment: Currently, but that obviously isn't sustainable in the longer term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Require.js does not enforce any specific structure of your files. You can either specify the full paths in the require configuration, or just use the full path in the require() or define() calls. Both will work, however the latter will save you some typing and makes it easier to move stuff around when you include something from a lot of different places:

```
var $ = require("third-party/jquery");
```

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "third-party/jquery"
    }
});
var $ = require("jquery");
```

> I want to be able to load the modules independently of each other. It should be possible for instance to remove the audio module from the engine, and it still work. It should also be easy to substitute modules, or add new modules.

This is not something require.js does four you. You can decide when and when not to load it, but you would have to make sure that it won't break the rest of your code.

> Also, I'm using jQuery for event handling, so it needs to be loaded before the engine is initiated.

You can do this in several different ways.

- require() it in your main.js so that it is always loaded (you can also use the require-jquery.js, which has jQuery included).
- Specify jQuery as a dependency of your engine

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "path.to.jquery",
        "engine": "path.to.engine"
    },
    shim: {
        "engine": {
            "deps": ["jquery"]
        }
    }
});
```

- Pass jQuery to the define() call in your module (probably the best choice)

```
define(["jquery"], function ($) {
    // your engine code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed answer! That should get me well on my way now